# How to get the image url of cocos2d-js Sprite?

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I have a Sprite created from the code:

```
var mysprite = new cc.Sprite(theURLofimage);
```

Now, At some point in my code, I wanted to get the "theURLofimage" of the above sprite.

```
var req_url = mysprite.texture.url;
```

returns me the required url in the browser. However, it returns undefined in the native code(or jsb, so to say). When I log "mysprite.texture", it returns me [object texture2D] but I cannot view the content of the object in the Cocos IDE console.

Is there anyway to get the required url form the sprite? or what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to take a look at the API docs to see if there's a better way, but you could just put it manually:

```
var mysprite = new cc.Sprite(theURLofimage);
mysprite.url = theURLofimage;
```

Then you could always get it from there.

Comment: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/html5-js/V3.5/index.html is the link to the API.  setting the url return "Invalid native object" in the cocos2d-js bindings. But anyways, I have made url reference to the Layer object  so that I can always do a look up on there. So I don't need it anymore. Thanks for your effort though.